# Base aritmetic in bash

Tags: bash

I have a question. I wanted to count a number of parameters in a expression for a range.

Existing for now code part:

```
if [ -n "$@" ]; then
    name=$1

    # count=$(( $#-1 ))

    for a in [2..${count}]; do
        # some code
    done
fi
```

My questtion is, if there would be any difference  in between this two ones:

```
$#-1
```

and

```
1-$#
```

?

Thanks

Comment: Well, 5-1=4 and 1-5=-4 so yes there would be a difference.

Comment: if you're trying to use the base syntax, what do you expect a base of *minus* one (or minus anything) to mean?

Comment: @2e0byo: I thought about do a shift that the first element was not counted and that the loop don't get out of the range. I try the solution given by Fravadona bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want to iterate over the arguments starting from `$2`; in `bash` you can do it like this

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for a in "${@:2}"
do
    echo "$a"
done
```